# Should I refuse new job offer details?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, negotiation

If I have a job offer from another company and my current company asks for details on the new job offer should I refuse?  I know there is no advantage to giving the new company name so I wouldn't do that, but I'd like to tell my current company to offer what they think I am worth and see which company offers more.  Isn't giving information only going to hurt my own position, such as getting a matching counter instead of possibly more?  Or do companies usually not counter at all if they don't see your new offer?

Comment: Would you give your previous company the internal product cost sheet from your current job?  Information given to you in confidence needs to stay confidential.  Your long-term reputation and personal integrity are worth more than both job offers put together.

Comment: I agree with @WesleyLong: You can't give the old company any details unless the new company authorizes you to do so. Basic business ethics. _Generalities_ are fine (eg, how much they're offering you), but nothing that exposes the other company's plans or policies or practices, including their hiring practices.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I have already decided I will leave.  But if my previous company offers me more than my new company couldn't I use the counter offer to raise my new offer?

Comment: What is *your* end goal here?  Are you just trying to get a raise or are you actually wanting to leave?  If the former, I think you went about it the wrong way.  If the latter, then why would a counter offer even matter?  Either way, the only real harm than can come from this is if you have accepted the other position and then try to renegotiate based on a counter.  I think you'd quickly find yourself out of both jobs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really depends on why you found a new job in the first place. Did you look for a new job b/c you felt you weren't getting paid enough? If so, then tell them what you'd want to stay, not what you'd be making at the other company.

If you found a new job b/c you no longer liked the one you're in, then just tell them you are making more and move on without burning any bridges. More money won't make you like your job again.

I will say this though, if you do get a pay bump with your current company, and decide to stay, you are really putting yourself in a bad situation. You have let your company know that you can and will find a new job if need be. You may find yourself in a situation where your company keeps you just long enough to replace you, then you are fired.

I personally wouldn't stay with a job once I've decided to leave it, and I wouldn't want to burn a bridge by getting my current company to counter offer just so I could turn it down. That being said, I do know a few people that got his old company to counter offer, then they took that counter offer to the new company and got a bigger starting salary. This burned a bridge for them though.

Comment: If you recently asked for a raise, and were denied, are you less or more likely to burn a bridge with this "this is what I can get elsewhere" move. I suspect that if you asked nicely and rationally, first, before exploring other offers that might look better to the company. That said, I'm not sure I'd work for a company that denied a thoughtful raise request without a a polite and rational explanation.